# Excel 2010 Stop copied worksheets referencing original

Tags: excel

I have a workbook which is used for processing data sets.

It's set up in such a way that it processes a bunch of data that I copy and paste into tables, and after it does all the calculations, it spits out an output sheet, as well as a bunch of charts relating to the output sheet.

I then use the Copy to another workbook option to capture the output.

My problem is this: I do this one set at a time for Mon through Fri. However, each time I update the original, the copied worksheets update to reflect the changes, meaning by the end, I have 5 days' of Friday's processed data.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

I see that the copied/moved sheets still reference the original workbook by name...

Just tried this: Doesn't work:
XXXMaybe: moving the sheets to a new workbook instead of copying will help this, followed by closing the original processing workbook without saving, then reopening it in its blank state to process the next set of data.XXX

Thanks all.

edit: Excel 2010
edit 2: Moving then reopening doesn't help...

Comment: This might help https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/737670-excel-2007-copying-worksheet-to-another-file-keeps-reference-to-the-original-file.html